# MYSQL - Cannot be able to create foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

When i execute the below query it throws an error,

```
alter table `ttis`.`users` 
add constraint `FK_Role_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ROLE_ID`) REFERENCES `roles` (`ROLE_ID`)
```

Error:

```
Error Code : 1005
Can't create table 'ttis.#sql-9c_8a' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: can u show the table structure  of 2 tables , roles and ttis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this post: [13.6.4.4. FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and search for "150". It says here:

> If you re-create a table that was
>   dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key
>   constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types,
>   and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If
>   these are not satisfied, MySQL returns
>   error number 1005 and refers to error
>   150 in the error message.
>
> If MySQL reports an error number 1005
>   from a CREATE TABLE statement, and the
>   error message refers to error 150,
>   table creation failed because a
>   foreign key constraint was not
>   correctly formed. Similarly, if an
>   ALTER TABLE fails and it refers to
>   error 150, that means a foreign key
>   definition would be incorrectly formed
>   for the altered table. You can use
>   SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to display a
>   detailed explanation of the most
>   recent InnoDB foreign key error in the
>   server.

Comment: Yes, Primary field(Role_Id) type is unsigned int. but my foreign key field type is just signed int. That is the issue that throws error.
Thanks.